# What is the geometric interpretation of 3D matrix of minors when finding the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I find that I don't quite understand the geometric meaning of a 3D matrix of minors, when finding the inverse of a matrix. Why is each item of an A^-1 matrix a minor of the previous matrix A?

Comment: Some answers are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643994/physical-meaning-of-cofactor-and-adjugate-matrix)

Comment: Another approach is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254774/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-the-adjugate-matrix)